# Regarding the fuel pump

Tags: fuel-system, pump

My fuel pump is failing. There is a lot of leakage happening. Please provide me some tips for taking better care of the fuel pump

Comment: Mechanical? Electrical? Front mounted? Rear mounted? In-tank? Car make, model & year?

Answer (score 1):

There's really not much you can do, fuel pumps wear out and they all go eventually. You don't oil them, you don't grease them, they just do their job. The best you can do to extend a fuel pump's life is to make sure the fuel flow is unrestricted: check/change the fuel filter (on a diesel this is often done every service, on a gasoline/petrol car it's every 20,000 to 150,000 miles depending on the manufacturer), check fuel lines, etc.

In any case, if you have a leak you need to determine if it's leaking fuel or oil and act accordingly. If it's electronic then it's probably near the tank and an oil leak is not an issue, if it's mechanical it could be leaking oil from the engine through a seal. If it's mechanical and the leak is oil then you need a gasket replacement, and the pump should be checked for condition to see whether that needs to be swapped as well. If it is leaking fuel then it's definitely time for a replacement unit.

Comment: The only *real* thing you can do, besides what you've stated, is to ensure you have some fuel in the tank. Most in-tank electric fuel pumps utilize the fuel to cool them. If you continually run your tank low of fuel, the pump can overheat which will shorten its lifespan. Keeping at least a 1/4 tank of fuel in the vehicle is enough to keep it cooled in most cases.